# RxJava Observable.create not emitting events for switchIfEmpty(observable)

Tags: java, rx-java2

I was experimenting with RxJava operators and came across this issue and don't know why it's behaving the way it is.
Let me walk through an example and hopefully the problem will be clear.

I have a fruits Observable which I created using Observable.just

```
Observable<String> fruits = Observable.just("Apple", "Banana", "Mango", "Strawberry", "Raspberry", "Blood Oranges");
```

I have another languages observable which I created using Observable.create

```
Observable<String> pLanguages = Observable.create(emitter -> {
            emitter.onNext("Kotlin");
            emitter.onNext("Java");
            emitter.onNext("Python");
            emitter.onNext("Javascript");
            emitter.onNext("Go");
            emitter.onNext("C");
            emitter.onNext("Rust");
        });
```

The switchIfEmpty() operator will subscribe to the operator which we pass to it if the source operator doesn't emit any observables.

Using this filter, I should see the fruits being emitted based on the definition of switchIfEmpty().

```
pLanguages.filter(s -> s.startsWith("Z"))
                .switchIfEmpty(fruits)
                .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println, () -> System.out.println("Complete"));
```

But I don't see any emissions. However, if I switch the observables like so

```
fruits.filter(s -> s.startsWith("Z"))
                .switchIfEmpty(pLanguages)
                .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println, () -> System.out.println("Complete"));
```

I do see the pLanguages observer emitting events. I've tried to debug but not sure why the Observable.create() is not emitting an empty observable for the switchIfEmpty() operator while Observable.just() does. I've spent couple of hours on this and hoping someone here can answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Summary**

You need to signal a completion on the `languages` source

**Example (based on the provided source code)**

```java
Observable<String> pLanguages = Observable.create(emitter -> {
    emitter.onNext("Kotlin");
    emitter.onNext("Java");
    emitter.onNext("Python");
    emitter.onNext("Javascript");
    emitter.onNext("Go");
    emitter.onNext("C");
    emitter.onNext("Rust");
    emitter.onComplete();
});
```

**Example in Kotlin (addt'l)**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val numbers = Observable.just("one", "two", "three")
    val languages = Observable.create<String> { emitter ->
        emitter.onNext("java")
        emitter.onNext("kotlin")
        emitter.onNext("swift")
        emitter.onComplete() // <-- Invoke this
    }

    languages
            .filter { s -> s.toLowerCase().startsWith("z") }
            .switchIfEmpty(numbers)
            .subscribe({
                System.out.println(it)
            }, {
                System.out.println(it)
            })

    numbers
            .filter { s -> s.toLowerCase().startsWith("z") }
            .switchIfEmpty(languages)
            .subscribe({
                System.out.println(it)
            }, {
                System.out.println(it)
            })


}
```

**Output**

```
one
two
three
java
kotlin
swift
```

**Read more on**

- http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Emitter.html